# Debugging Spark standalone cluster with idea

Tags: macos, debugging, apache-spark

I am trying to debug a Spark Application on a local cluster using a master and a worker nodes. I have been successful at setting up the master node and worker nodes using Spark standalone cluster manager with `start-master.sh` and it works.But I want to how Spark Application works in the spark cluster, so I want to start the cluster in debug mode. I read the `start-master.sh` code， mock the args   and start `org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master` main method.Unfortunately it gets a NoClassDefFoundError,I can't open the webui. I want to know where the problem is.

The Error is :

```
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPool
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachPage(WebUI.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ui.MasterWebUI.initialize(MasterWebUI.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.ui.MasterWebUI.<init>(MasterWebUI.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.onStart(Master.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

my debug configurations is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwKKl.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to even use a spark standalone cluster for debugging.

1. You can run spark locally in the your IDE with breakpoints.
2. Spark provides you option to run locally pointing to local filesystem as HDFS.

Please follow the following link to know more about how to write test cases for local mode in spark
http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/word-count-in-spark/

Comment: I prefer this approach as well.  Another advantage is that by running in local mode, which is effectively running an embedded Spark engine, you can run and debug your integration tests directly in your IDE without having to launch any services.